# How do I change initial Twilio Flex WebChat message from "BOT" to a more friendly name?

Tags: twilio, twilio-flex

I can see that by default the first message that is shown to the end user is from "BOT" . How do I change this to something a little more "human"? Perhaps something like "Agent"?

Id imagine customers a little apprehensive about just talking to a robot?

screenshot below of default "from"

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The initial name "Bot" comes from [templated strings in the FlexWebChat manager](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/localization-and-ui-templating). The template string for the name is `PredefinedChatMessageAuthorName`.

You can override these strings once you have a FlexWebChat manager instance. To change the `PredefinedChatMessageAuthorName` you would do the following:

```
FlexWebChat.Manager.create(configuration)
    .then(manager => {
        manager.strings.PredefinedChatMessageAuthorName = "Agent";

        ReactDOM.render(
            <FlexWebChat.ContextProvider manager={manager}>
                <Flex.RootContainer />
            </FlexWebChat.ContextProvider>,
            document.getElementById("root")
        );
    });
```

Let me know if that helps at all.